# Mockito тестирование

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, mockito

Тестирую метод 1. В методе 1 есть статический вызов метода 2 на объекте другого класса. Могу ли я как-то задать поведение метода 2 по типу

Mockito.when( ClassName.2() ).thenReturn(...);

???

Comment: Mockito так не умеет, смотрите PowerMockito.